# Transfer files on SSH to Desktop

Tags: ssh, scp

Based on the tutorials I've browsed through:

> This is the Linux scp command syntax to retrieve file or directory from a remote computer:

```
scp -r [login name@ip address] : [/path/filename] .
```

So what exactly is /path/filename on your own computer? What is root? Is it C drive? Is it current User folder? (Windows OS here)

Comment: From what machine to what machine do you want to transfer and from what machine are you issuing the command ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows, you want to download [**WinSCP**](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php).

Answer (score 1):

The `.` at the end of the command is the destination pathname, so for that command, it is the current directory. The `-r` option is used to recursively copy directories, so leave it off if you only intend to copy a single file. Also, the spaces on either side of the colon (`:`) should not be there. Here's an example, with a more complicated destination:

```
C:\> scp user@myhost.example.com:/home/user/myfile %userprofile%\Desktop\myfile
```

Comment: So if I'm using Putty which is executed from my desktop, the "." will download the file to my desktop?

Comment: `.` always refers to your current directory (i.e. what you see before the `>` in your CMD.EXE prompt. I'm not super-familiar with using PuTTY from the command line.